# How to paste image from clipboard using javascript in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, clipboarddata

I'm trying to handle PrintScreen paste in a `textarea`, which is working everywhere except in Safari. Since Safari is a kind of webkit it has `event.clipboardData` object. But in Chrome it is a DataTransfer and works fine. It does not work in Safari, and I'm failed to find the reason in docs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').bind('paste', function(evt){
        console.log(evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no question here. :) Yes, right, it is not working in Safari.
Look here (http://codebits.glennjones.net/copypaste/pasteimagedata.htm) and check browsers compatibility and see live example.

Comment: By the way JIRA have fixed this issue: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-37805
According to this task JIRA is able to paste images from clipboard in Safari since 6.2.4. I don't know how.

Comment: @farghost, do you have new information regarding this issue? thanks

Comment: unfortunately not, I don't have new info.